# Corresponding Sqlite query syntax for Mysql query

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Please help me to find the sqlite equivalent of the below query. Tried searching a lot.

```
    SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, id
FROM tbl_flight
ORDER BY id DESC
) AS tbl_flight WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do (what your query should return) in your question, so that people with similar problems can find this question in the future. (Could also help people that are familiar with sqlite but not mysql to give you an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a single query, but you can use temporary tables and the rowid property of every table:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f0a1b/8 (You can't run the fiddle twice, you have to always rebuild schema first before running it again)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS 
  SELECT id
  FROM tbl_flight
  ORDER BY id DESC;

SELECT tmp.rowid AS rank, tmp.id FROM tmp WHERE id=2;
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you switch to SQLite (WebSQL) and run your code in that environment, you don't get that I/O error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f0a1b/2  Must be something strange with SQL.js

Comment: Also this version doesn't seem to have that problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f0a1b/10